# How to escape an ng-Repeat loop?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have the following ng-repeat loops that unpack JSON data into an Accordion:

```
<accordion close-others="oneAtATime">
    <accordion-group ng-repeat="service in userPF.custom.services">
        <accordion-heading><input type="checkbox" name="status" disabled>On <input type="checkbox" name="status" disabled checked>Off {{service.name}}</accordion-heading>
        Related Items:<br>
        <div class="secondary" ng-repeat="fields in userPF.custom.fields">
            <span ng-show="checkForMatch(service.name, fields.services)">
                <span ng-repeat="value in fields.values">
                    {{value.name}}<br>
                </span>
            </span>
        </div>
    </accordion-group>
</accordion>
```

The first trip through the loop {{service.name}} will always return data but the second value {{value.name}} might not.  If it doesn't I don't want the div or span to render, just the heading.  I've tried some variations on ng-if but haven't come close to being able to tell if I'm getting data back or not.

Comment: Can you put your example online with the relevant objects in site like plunker or jsfiddle?

Comment: The controller is enormous but I think I can put up just this little bit, yes.  Will take me a minute...

Comment: Just curious.  What's wrong with what you have now?  If there's nothing in `fields.values` then that `ng-repeat` won't do anything.

Comment: ...except it still draws the div and span which then populates as a blank box in the accordion.

Comment: Wouldn't that be your answer then? `ng-if="fields.values"` on the div would show it only if it had values.

Comment: @yossico, I'm not trying to be difficult but I'm pretty sure all the logic you need to look at is right here.  I'm not seeing anything in the controller that would add to the understanding of the question.  Do you have any specific questions?

Comment: @MatthewGreen but maybe then I've got the repeat looks out of order because it doesn't check field.values until it's already rendered the outer part of the span.  I need everything from </accordion-heading> to </accordion group> to go away if there's nothing in fields.values.  I suppose I could disable the accordion item but then that takes it out of step with everything else...

Comment: @DaveKaye I dont need all your controller, I just want to see the data that gives you hard time, If you can simulate the situation I can solve it in no time

Comment: @yossico I don't really know how to use Plunkr or JSFiddle with Angular so this doesn't *quite* work but I think all the code you need is here: plnkr.co/edit/DLXZHQtQTjsQjDc1fdqQ?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Refer this Link.
AS this code shows and its working fine you can have ng-show inside ng-repeat.

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="RepeatTestCtrl">
    <ul ng-repeat="item in items">
        <li ng-show="item.id.length == 0">{{item.name}} is even</li>
        <li ng-show="item.id % 2 == 1">{{item.name}} is odd</li>
    </ul>
</div>

function RepeatTestCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.items = [
        { id: 1, name: 'test 1' },
        { id: 2, name: 'test 2' },
        { id: 3, name: 'test 3' },
        { id: 4, name: 'test 4' }
    ];
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/b004t06z/41/

Comment: Here based on Length , Even will never get displayed

Comment: This is not necessarily a wrong solution, but it doesn't remove the item from the DOM it only doesn't show it.  So still shows up in the Accordion.  Maybe I need to reorder the repeat loops...

Comment: Oh !! Yeah....I forgot your base requirements that are in accordin , Sorry , you have to rearrange logic like if data is there then only show accordin